# Child CSS3 transitions not working in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an h1 element and its child element animated using CSS3 transitions. Everything works well in Chrome and even IE 10+, but in Firefox the transition effects are only seen in the parent element and not the child element.

The code is as such

```
<h1>G<span>eneric</span> D<span>ata</span> B<span>inder</span></h1>
```

Where the h1 element and the span element both have their own transitions as such:

```
h1{
    transition: all 800ms;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms;
    -o-transition: all 800ms;
    transition-property: line-height,width,font-size;
    -moz-transition-property: line-height,width,font-size;
    -ms-transition-property: line-height,width,font-size;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 span{
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:500px;
    transition: all 800ms;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms;
    -o-transition: all 800ms;
    transition-property: opacity,max-width;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity,max-width;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity,max-width;
}
```

The effect can be seen here: [Generic Data Binder Site](http://gdb.thewebdev.guru)

Is the issue here a bug or caveat in FireFox's rendering engine, or I'm there something key I'm missing such that I'm making a silly mistake?

Comment: I just downloaded the FF 29 Beta, however I'm still seeing the incorrect behavior. Instead of the letters smoothly fading out, they instantly disappear where the H1 element is the only thing smoothly transitioning.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: CSS3 sounds and all but the truth of the matter is that it's not ready yet.. and performance isn't great either. I'd recommend checking out GSAP animation tool and look at the CSS vs JS animations performance. http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html

Comment: Is there a reason why you specify `all` for all your transitions and then selectively override `transition-property` on just a few of the prefixes? Also, `-ms-transition` is not used anymore, so it can be removed with no real consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289: the change in the `position` value (to/from `fixed`) on the parent forces box reconstruction, which loses the old style info on the kids, which therefore do not transition.

Comment: Thank you so much! You nailed it! I used a messy hack for FireFox. In the context of this issue, starting with position fixed vs absolute is a minor difference, but I figure if I can still have it my way exactly in other browsers, I'll do that.

`@-moz-document url-prefix() { h1{ position:fixed; } }`